# Symfony2 Validator failed for two embed entities with same name field

Tags: php, symfony, validation, entities

I have two entities, Stock and Country related with a Many-to-One relation. 
Both have a field named "acronym".

The form for adding a stock display the Stock acronym field and a list of Country.

When a new Stock is saved in the controller, it failed with the message "This value should not be blank". It appear it's caused by tha validator (NotBlank) from the Country acronym field.

Two solutions so far:
1. rename Stock acronym field to stock_acronym;
2. or remove the validator NotBlank for the Country acronym field.

In both case it solved the problem, but I'd like to find a cleaner solution...

Here is some code:

```
class Stock
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $acronym
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="acronym", type="string", length=10)
     * @Assert\MinLength(
     *     limit=2,
     *     message="Acronym must have at least {{ limit}} characters."
     * )
     */
    private $acronym;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\GeoBundle\Entity\Country", inversedBy="country_stocks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $country;
```

.....

```
class Country
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $country_name
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="country_name", type="string", length=70)

     */
    private $country_name;

    /**
     * @var string $country_name
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="acronym", type="string", length=2)
     */
    private $acronym;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Admin\GeoBundle\Entity\Stock", mappedBy="country")
 * @var ArrayCollection $country_stocks
 */
protected $country_stocks;
```

.....

StockType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('acronym'); // this is the Stock acronym
    $builder->add('country', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'Admin\GeoBundle\Entity\Country',
        'property' => 'country_name',
        'query_builder' => function (\Admin\GeoBundle\Entity\CountryRepository $repository)
                            {return $repository->createQueryBuilder('s');}
                ));
}
```

.....

Stock Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/stock/add/{id}", name="_admin_stock_add", requirements = {"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = null})
 * @Template()
 */
public function addAction($id)
{
  $request = $this->get('request');
  $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

  if($id){
    $stock = $em->getRepository('AdminGeoBundle:Stock')->find($id);
    if (null === $stock){
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The stock to be edited could not be found');
    }
  }else{
    $stock = new \Admin\GeoBundle\Entity\Stock();
  }

  $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new \Admin\GeoBundle\Form\Type\StockType(), $stock);

  if ('POST' == $request->getMethod()){
      $form->bindRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()){
            if(!$id){
              $stock->SetCreated(new \Datetime());
              $em->persist($stock);
            }
            $em->flush();
        }else{
          var_dump($form->getErrors());
        }
  }
  return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_admin_stock'));  
}
```